# Need to get following output : `<<<<<>>>===` from Input `str1='<><<>>=<==<'` using python

Tags: python, string

I have a scenario where i am trying to print the input in sequence like below:

- First need to print less than symbol
- then Greater than symbol
- after then equal to symbol

As I know only below approach to get the Output, is there any concise approach to get the expected output with few lines of code

I am not aware of any another approach than below , if any other approach solution is appreciated

**My Code:**

```
str1='<><<>>=<==<'
c=[]
e=[]
f=[]
d=[]
for a in str1:
    if a=="<":
        c.append(a)
for i in str1:
    if i==">":
        e.append(i)
for y in str1:
    if y=="=":
        f.append(y)
d=c+e+f
print(d)
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<<<<<>>>===
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate 3 times on the input, you can do it once and build your 3 lists at the same time. You can also simply count each type of char - and might want to use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to repeat a character, combined with a generator expression:

```
>>> "".join(s*str1.count(s) for s in "<>=")
'<<<<<>>>==='
```

Comment: this answer is `O(n^2)`

Comment: ...and how do you generate the hashmap? Besides this is `O(3n)` which is equivalent to `O(n)`.

Comment: I don't do that, Counter do this ;)

Comment: exactly. yes for 3 is O(3*n) but for m is O(m*n)

Comment: at the end m=n, for every char you run count and this O(n*n) = O(n^2)

Comment: what is run time for this `12345678abcdef...`

Comment: for every char you run count

Comment: @user1740577 It's still `O(3n)`. The loop iterates over `"<>="`, not `str1`.

Comment: for this question, I say O(3*n) but this answer for all-purpose is O(n^2)

Comment: @user1740577 No, it's `O(m*n)` for the general case, never `O(n^2)`, and `m` is always a constant because it must be a sorted set. It can be all characters in the Unicode alphabet, but still finite. `n`, on the other hand, has no upper bound as `str1` can have repeating elements.

Comment: why are you insistence your words? I ask what is runtime when s = `123456789abcdef...` and you count for every char and every char repeat one time for this bad case runtime is `O(n^2) , m==n`

Comment: @user1740577 Your argument is flawed. The question is for limited set of character matches (bounded m=3, unbounded n). Even if the m in question was variable, then what Selcuk says is still correct. The values of unique ascii characters (or even extended ascii) is a limited set, so it's easy to pick an arbitrary const C that will always be higher than m. So we can say that here `O(m*n) == O(C*n) == O(n)`. That's not to say that there isn't a performance gain for in reducing unnecessary linear loops, but that does not change the time complexity of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try ths:

```
str1='<><<>>=<==<'

from collections import Counter

dct = Counter(str1)
''.join((s*dct[s]) for s in '<>=')
# '<<<<<>>>==='
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of < symbol, > symbol and = symbol first using `.count()` method. Then, print the symbols accordingly.

```
str1 = '<><<>>=<==<'
output = '<'*str1.count('<')+'>'*str1.count('>')+'='*str1.count('=')
print(output) #<<<<<>>>===
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using `collections.Counter` but it relies on the order of characters encountered:

```
str1='<><<>>=<==<'

from collections import Counter

print(''.join(Counter(str1).elements()))

# Prints: <<<<<>>>===
```